# I am trying to render an <img> tag using a ternary operator in my react component, but when I run the code my <img> tag is ignored

Tags: reactjs, image, jsx

This is my original code that renders my img tag fine:

```
    import React from 'react' 
    import './Arena.css'

    function Arena({ phase }) {

return (
    <div className='backBoard'>
        <div className='canvas'>

        <img style={{height:"320px", width: '280px'}} src= 
   {require('./stickman/11.png')}/>

        </div>
    </div>)
    }

    export default Arena
```

phase = the integer 0 passed down with props..
I tried this:

```
import React from 'react' 
import './Arena.css'

function Arena({ phase }) {

return (
    <div className='backBoard'>
        <div className='canvas'>

        {
            phase === 0
            ?
            <img style={{height:"320px", width: 
'280px'}} 
    src={require('./stickman/11.png')}/>
            :
            "not image"

        }

        </div>
    </div>)
}

export default Arena
```

When my webpage is rendered, the "not image" string is what the ternary operator returns. Is there a different conditional statement that works for this particular situation? Or maybe a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a different conditional statement that works for this particular situation?

You can use "&&", check the example bellow.

About your question, are you sure about your "phase" prop being 0?

Try this and cut and paste the console.log output:

```
import React from 'react' 
import './Arena.css'

const Arena = ({ phase }) => {
  console.log(phase);
  console.log(typeof phase);
  return (
    <div className='backBoard'>
        <div className='canvas'>
        {
            (phase === 0) && (
              <img
                style={{height:"320px", width: '280px'}} 
                src={require('./stickman/11.png')} />
            )
        }
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Arena
```

It should print 0 and 'number'.